# Get remote x display working in linux without ssh tunneling

Tags: linux, remote

I need to get an x window to display on 'nathanb-box' from 'ceres' without tunneling X over ssh.

```
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~] xhost +ceres
ceres being added to access control list
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~] xhost +ceres.foo.com
ceres.foo.com being added to access control list
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~] echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~] xauth list | grep nathanb
nathanb-box.foo.com:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a27ad72172460013c07e3a31b0d7d6da
```

On ceres...

```
[nathanb@ceres ~] export DISPLAY=nathanb-box.foo.com:0.0
[nathanb@ceres ~] xauth list | grep nathanb
nathanb-box.foo.com:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a27ad72172460013c07e3a31b0d7d6da
[nathanb@ceres ~] xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: nathanb-box.foo.com:0.0
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that X was being started with -nolisten tcp. I removed "-nolisten tcp" from

/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc

and it works like a charm.

Comment: in that case you might consider closing the question

Comment: Please elaborate on the solution. What you've provided is only confirmation that you have fixed it.