# Configure X connections over TCP without using an X connection

Tags: linux, remote-access, xorg

I want to run a GUI application on a remote machine I only have ssh access to. I don't need to, or want to, see the GUI window. (I know I could use something like `ssh -C -X remote_server` if I wanted the GUI to be on my client.)

I know X is running on the remote machine, as `ps` shows this:

```
root  ... /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7
```

I set `DISPLAY=:0.0` but I then get "Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server" when I try to use it.

At [Get remote x display working in linux without ssh tunneling](https://superuser.com/questions/49240/get-remote-x-display-working-in-linux-without-ssh-tunneling) and [Xserver doesn't work unless DISPLAY=0.0](https://superuser.com/questions/128091/xserver-doesnt-work-unless-display-0-0) I see the advice to use gdmsetup to allow X to listen on TCP. But, gdmsetup is a GUI application! And trying to run it over ssh -X did not work ("X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication").

So, is there a text file I can edit to remove `-nolisten`? And, after editing it, how do I safely restart X, remotely? (There is other stuff running on this machine, so requesting a reboot is possible, but undesirable.) If not, *should* gdmsetup be able to run over ssh and I should persevere in that direction?

**UPDATE:** I had to do the `ssh -X` session as root (ssh as a normal user, then sudo or su, does not work.) So, I did the edit with gdmsetup. I then restarted X with `gdm-restart`. I've also done `xhost +` from that ssh -X session. The ps line no longer shows the `-nolisten tcp` part. But still no luck connecting to it, with either `DISPLAY=:0` or `DISPLAY=localhost:0`

**UPDATE#2:** I just noticed the reason `xauth +` hadn't helped (when done over `ssh -X`) was it altered my client machine, not the remote server! Oops. Good job I was inside the firewall! (I think the reason it had done this was related to the XAUTHORITY environmental variable, see Cougar's reply.)

Comment: Is the remote machine secure - could you just run `xhost +` to allow any user to access the X display, would that be enough?  If so then `xhost +` as the user that started X and the `export DISPLAY=:0` on the remote machine should be enough to direct output to the remote X and save you having to see it

Comment: Thanks @Paul   As root (over ssh) I did `xhost +` but got xhost:  unable to open display "". I then tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and tried again and instead got `Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server`, `Xlib: No protocol specified` and `xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

Comment: While the X server is owned by root, it almost certainly didn't start it, it runs as suid root.  One of the normal user account would have started X and that is the account you need to do the `xhost +` from

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Perhaps restarting gdm as root was enough to allow `xhost +` to run now. But it still hasn't helped (see my UPDATE above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it seems you want your app to attach to the session root owns right now: the gdm - login screen.

why don't you just launch your own xserver and your program:

```
%> startx /your/program -- :1
```

(Added by Darren) Here is precisely what I did. In one ssh session, become root, and type:

```
startx -- :1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
xhost + &
```

Then in another ssh session, normal user:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
xclock
```

(Just using xclock as a test.)

Comment: Thanks @akira. I couldn't startx as a normal user, and didn't want to run my app as root, so used two windows. Editing your answer seemed the best place to describe how I did that; I hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @Darren *Approved* — I think that's fine, always good to have a practical example.

Comment: if you can't launch `startx` as a normal user (ubuntu? debian?) then just cnfigure your system to let you launch `startx` as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to connect to the remotely running X display and start your program then it is just an authorization problem you have. Now it depends how the authorization is set up.

One way is to use xhost and give permissions per IP but this is highly unsecure because any programm running on this machine (or any machine if you just use +) can automatically connect with your X dislpay server.

The common way is to use X authority file. Then you just need to know this file and have an access to it. Now it depends on distribution if this file is .Xauthority in your home directory or is it some temporary file set up every time you start X session.

In first case everything works out of box, in latter case you need to know this temporary file name. One way to find it out is to look at XAUTHORITY variable in environment of some program (like windowmanager) already running under your X server. You can get environment variables easily from /proc/PID/environ file like this:

```
cat /proc/12345/environ | xargs -0 -L 1 echo | grep XAUTHORITY
```

Then just export XAUTHORITY and DISPLAY variables to your shell and start your program

Comment: Thanks @Cougar, that worked. I found centos keeps that file in /var/gdm. As a normal user exporting XAUTHORITY was no help. So, what I actually did was, as root, `export DISPLAY=:0;export XAUTHORITY=/var/gdm/:0.Xauth` then I was able to run `xhost +`.  After doing that I was able to login as a normal user, just do `export DISPLAY=:0` and now I can run X apps!

Comment: P.S. `xhost +` was just for quick testing. `xhost 127.0.0.1` is more sensible, and still works.

Comment: Why do you need xhost if you can provide XAUTHORITY directly to your app? ;-)

Comment: Not sure about the smiley, but if that was a serious question my understanding is `export XAUTHORITY` told root where to find the file that `xhost` will modify.

Comment: The problem with xhost is that it gives access to all programs coming from that IP address. You do not need to open access with xhost if you already know XAUTHORITY. xhost can be used in very closed and controlled environment but even then I would try to avoid it.

Comment: Could you give a full example explaining what you mean by "know XAUTHORITY". As a test, as root I did `startx -- :1 &`. It creates `/path/to/.serverauth.1543`. For the test I did `chmod 666` on that file. Then I started another ssh session, as a normal user, did `export DISPLAY=:1`, but I don't have permission to start an X app. So then I did `export XAUTHORITY=/path/to/.serverauth.1543` But it still does not allow me access.

Comment: The /path/to/.serverauth.1543 is not the right one. Check the XAUTHORITY variable of the first process running under your X which is usually windowmanager. This is the right file you have to use. You can check if you have auth entry for hostname:1 in your XAUTHORITY file by 'xauth -f $XAUTHORITY list'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going to a great length to make it work. As an alternative, I could recommend installing FreeNX on the remote machine and access it with NXClient. You will get a full remote desktop via ssh and you will be able just open terminal window and run your app. This will take less time then trying to figure out the tunneling with ssh.

Comment: Thanks @dtoubelis. That is an interesting answer for a different question (I think VNC is also used for this?); also ssh tunneling works fine. The question here was how to start an app over ssh when that app insists on wanting to show a window (even though I don't want or need to see its window). `export DISPLAY=:0` was the simple answer to that; everything else here was working around the security!

Comment: @Darren Cook: I was not trying to answer your question in itself but rather to offer an alternative solution to your problem. I personally find ssh tunneling to cumbersome and I usually opt for simpler solutions. And, yes VNC is another alternative but it is not nearly as good as FreeNX.